# Continuous functions and limits inequalities

Tags: calculus

Is it true that if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both continuous functions and $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) \leq \lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)?$$

It makes sense to me but I'm not sure.

Comment: continuity is not necessary, what is necessary is that both the limits you are talking about exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If f,g are both continuous, they're both defined at every limit at a point. Also, since f(x) $\leq$ g(x) for all x$\in \mathbb R$, then g(x)- f (x) $\geq 0$ for every x. Therefore, regardless of the limits, the value of g(x) will always be at least as large as that of f(x) for every x. So  $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) \leq \lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)$.

You didn't ask for a formal proof, so I didn't give you one. It should be straightforward to produce one.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter if they are continuous or not. Consider the function $h(x) = g(x) - f(x)$. $h(x) \ge 0$. Then let $A = \lim\limits_{x\to \infty} h(x)$. If $A < 0$ by definition of limit (for $\epsilon = {A \over 2}$) $\exists x: \forall y>x: h(y) < {A \over 2}$. It's not possible since $h(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

As $f$ and $g$ are continuous and $f\leq g$, so if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) =\infty$, then we have $ \lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty$. Otherwise, if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\alpha< \infty$, it is vivid that $\alpha\leq \lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)$. If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=-\infty$, there is nothing to prove. So, we have $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) \leq \lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)$.